# Replace double slashes to four slashes

Tags: c++, replace, backslash

I have char data type that contain a directory with double slashes. I want to replace the double slashes to four slashes so that my output will be double slashes. I had tried a lots of solutions, but nothing works.

```
char *str = "C:\\Users\\user\\desktop";
for(int i = 0;i < strlen(str) ; i++)
    if(str[i] == '\\')  
    str[i] =='\\\\';
```

The output of this code shows 'C:\Users\user\desktop'.

Comment: why not use regex_replace()?

Comment: @TejasPatel Not every project uses C++11 and/or Boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, since you're using c++, consider using `std::string`. Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior (either copy the string literal into a buffer, or use a `char []` or `std::string` in the first place.)

Second, string literals must be enclosed in double quotes.

Third, you require two sets of backslashes for every backslash you escape. `\\\\` turns into `\\`.

---

This should do the trick:

```
std::string s("C:\\Users\\user\\desktop");
auto it = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), '\\');
while (it != s.end()) {
    auto it2 = s.insert(it, '\\');

    // skip over the slashes we just inserted
    it = std::find(it2+2, s.end(), '\\');
}
std::cout << s; // C:\\Users\\user\\desktop
```

Comment: For C++03 - `for(std::string::iterator it = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), '\\'); it != s.end(); it = std::find(it, s.end(), '\\')) { it = s.insert(it, '\\') + 2; }`

Answer (score 0):

So the first sentence is incorrect -- you do *not* have a directory with double slashes.  The `\\` in the string literal represents just a single character in the actual string.

If you do want to do this, a single replacement won't work, as that will overwrite your next character.  You'll have to build a whole new string, moving one character at a time (and occasionally writing an extra character to the output).

However, I suspect that's a really big *If* in that previous sentence.  Are you sure that you actually need doubled slashes?  There may be a reason for it, but I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: Might be good to note that the backslash is interpreted as the beginning of an [escape sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).