# How to find a string containing backslash character in a line in C++?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, special-characters

I am using MSVS2010 to code a C++ program.I have a string with value `HAI\HOW_ARE\YOU`. I stored it into the string from a file(read using istringstream). Now, I am opening another file and I have to check whether the same string exists in any of the lines. I used the following code:

```
while(!file.eof())
{
    getline(file,line_read);
    if(line_read.find(search_word)!=string::npos) // search_word = "HAI\HOW_ARE\YOU"
            break;
    else 
        getline(file,readline);// skip a line
}
```

But even if `line_read` contains `search_word`, the control goes to else part. I understood that it is due to the `\` character in the string because the following code worked:

```
while(!file.eof())
{
    getline(file,line_read);
    if(line_read.find("HAI\\HOW_ARE\\YOU")!=string::npos) \\ included double slash
            break;
    else 
        getline(file,readline);// skip a line
}
```

So I tried replacing `\` by `\\` using [Replace double slashes to four slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810784/replace-double-slashes-to-four-slashes?rq=1). But it also passed control to `else` part.

I cannot find by manually typing the string as I have to compare a lot of strings in this manner. Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I understood that it is due to the \ character in the string because the following code worked"_. Yes, probably...where search_word is defined? String escaping is only a compiler time things.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: It is defined in a function in another program(say read.cpp). The above mentioned code is a part of test.cpp. I get the value of search_word in test.cpp (I checked it using breakpoints and watch).

Comment: Why do you skip a line if the current line doesn't contain search_word?

Comment: @anorm: To make the code simple, I have removed certain lines of code. Actually the `if` works only if the `line_read` contains a specific start symbol.The line next to it will never contain 'search_word'.

Comment: the `\\\` representing the backslash character. can you show your input file? (I mean to the section with the search word...)

Comment: @Anzz OK, but you're only checking every other line for search_word

Comment: @SHR : it is the `setupapi.dev.log` file in the Windows system (`C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log`). section with `search_word` is the first line of each session(line starting with ">>>").

Comment: @anorm: I am checking only the lines starting with ">>>". The line following this will also contain ">>>". That is why I skip it. All other lines are skipped from this `if-else` part.

Comment: And of course, you're probably checking the last line twice.  You probably want `while ( std::getline( file, line_read ) )`; at any rate, you don't want to do anything with `line_read` before you verify that `std::getline` succeeded.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. what you are looking for? how you wrote it in your code? how it written in the file?

Comment: @Anzz To me it seems like you're skipping it if the current line DOES NOT include your search word.

Comment: @SHR: As I didnt want to make it seem complicated, I used a simple string. If you have gone through the file, you would have found it as `USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX\serialnumber`

Comment: The logic is ok.. what I require is a way to find if this substring exists in the line just read. How to overcome the issue caused by backslash.

Comment: @Anzz In your source it should be: "USB\\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX\\serialnumber". but you need to b sure not to skip the line...

Comment: @SHR: That line is not being skipped... I am sure about that..

Comment: @Anzz Can you tell what is the return value of the find with the line? you can try to print the line and the search string. and compare.

Comment: If I am not wrong it is a size_t value. If the searched string is not found,it returns `string::npos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a string had read from a file, you don't need to replace the backslashes with double backslashes.

you only uses `\\` to represent a single backslash in strings on source files, to indicate you mean the backslash as is, not as escape character.

Try to run the following code, change the find string to your find string.

For me it printed 4 lines.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

string find_str; = "USB\\VID_04E8&PID_6860\\4df73c04056fbfa5";

int main()
{
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    ifstream fin("C:\\Windows\\Inf\\setupapi.dev.log");
    string line;
    while(std::getline(fin,line)){
        if(line.find(find_str)!=string::npos){
            cout<<line<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
if I read the search string from a file it will look like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    ifstream fin("C:\\Windows\\Inf\\setupapi.dev.log");
    string find_str;
    string line;
    input>>find_str;
    while(std::getline(fin,line)){
        if(line.find(find_str)!=string::npos){
            cout<<line<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If input.txt file is:

```
USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860\4df73c04056fbfa5
```

I'm getting the same results.

Comment: I tried this before and it worked... But can you check by reading the value of `find._str` from a file rather than assigning it ourselves.